# How to see the rendered HTML page, not code, in Firefox

Tags: html, linux, web, vim, browser

I wrote a simple HTML page, and when I open it in Firefox, it doesn’t show the web page but the code.

I think the problem is Vim because it’s like that doesn’t recognize characters such as comments(#) etc.

Comment: Vim is an editor, and it edits text files. If a browser, which is downstream from what Vim does, can't make sense of an HTML file, then it's the HTML, not the editor. There's no relationship between them. Your question is poorly asked. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We need the absolute smallest HTML file that duplicates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the problem is **not** Vim, since its sole purpose is to be a plaintext editor. It allows you to edit a file, and doesn't really do much else (but boy, can it do that job well).

Are you sure the file has `.html` as its extension? Browsers tend to judge a file's characteristics almost exclusively on its extension, so if it's saved as a `.txt` file or something else then it will just show the plaintext.

---

I also just noticed your line about comments with a hash (`#`). These do not constitute comments in HTML, and will probably break things in more ways than one. If you're commenting something in HTML, make sure you use `<!--` and `-->` as the delimiters, respectively.

Comment: Ok perfect thanks I’ve changed the comments as you said and it’s seems to work, Now I added variables to the code but I can’t recall them in the body...I’m using the character ($) to recall them. Is it right?

Comment: To my knowledge, HTML doesn't have any widely used system for variables. HTML is less of a scripting language such as Bash, which *does* use `$` to denote variables, and is more for formatting style.

Comment: Please don't use "edit" or "update" tags when you change your text. We can tell what changed and when if necessary. Readability and comprehension are more important, so simply add/change in the body as if it'd been there all along.

Comment: HTML has _NO_ system for variables. It's a markup language, not a general-purpose language. Languages implement various ways of pre-parsing the HTML and searching for specific tags and replacing them, but that's not an aspect or feature of HTML.